# Is IKVM on Monotouch a supported/tested deployment of the VM?

Tags: java, iphone, xamarin.ios, ikvm

It seems that running the IKVM on monotouch is one possible method for deploying Java applications on the iPhone. Is this combination one that has been tested and is being successfully used in the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran across this old question while editing a new one. There is a new fork of IKVM specifically for targeting monotouch:

https://github.com/samskivert/ikvm-monotouch

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you want do. IKVM runs the best with the .NET framework from MS. With MONO on Windows, it is slightly worse. With MONO on Linux, it is even worse yet.

I think many will run on Monotouch. The GUI can be problematic. I have not tested it. And I think it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

To date (Nov 23, 2010) this is not a supported, or tested, deployment of the VM.

Some applications may run properly, but expect challenges. Beyond the standard problems with an untested deployment, also expect that:

- some UI components will not work on the iPhone
- many UI items will appear out of place (not matching the standard Apple look)
- crashes/bugs/problems will likely be difficult to debug/analyze, due to the high number of levels of abstraction.